# Angular 6 symbolic link module not found

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I have created Angular module which I would like to use inside another Angular SPA.For this I created symbolic Link for my external module inside the SPA.

Root
|
---SharedModule
|
|
---SPA
  |
  ------SharedModule (symbolik link)

When I do ng build on my spa, I am getting shared module not found error.

It is defined in the appModule.ts file as

```
import { SharedComponentsModule } from './SharedModule/shared-components.module';
```

-- UPDATE
Fixed the typo, sorry this was in my question not in my code. All paths are correct

Comment: Typo? `SharedMofule`

Comment: Sounds strange to me having a symbolik link..Why you just don't create a library?

Comment: because if I change symbolink it will also reflect in another projects. Library will have to be re installed to get latest update right ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error while import

change "SharedMofule" to "SharedModule"

**changed import:**

```
import { SharedComponentsModule } from './SharedModule/shared-components.module';
```

Answer (score 0):

After applying mklink /d command , it works fine now. Earlier I used mkink /J command which is giving issue.

Comment: under which operating system was this?